# Cannot Connect to MSSQL Server with PHP (running on Linux Debian) - (ODBC Driver Missing)

Tags: php, sql, debian, odbc

We are trying to connect a simple PHP code to the SQL Server Database on another server. But this error appears:

> Connection could not be established.

```
<?php 

Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 01000[SQLSTATE] => 01000[1] => 0[code] => 0[2] => [unixODBC][DriverManager]Can't open lib 'ODBCDriver13
        for SQLServer' : file not found [message] => [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can'topenlib'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server':
            filenotfound
        )
    )
```

I know that the problem resides on ODBC not being installed. But I am not sure about how to install it. We are using Debian 8 and we already installed the sql server driver for PHP. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in Github. It gave a clear and specific step-by-step on how to install ODBC in Ubuntu.

https://gist.github.com/joecampo/6f777a659b8132b9d6fe1c3589df394c